# What is the event space area?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, area

I have graphed out $9.5 \leq x+y < 10.5,$ which is the set of numbers that satisfy the problem's conditions, and the sample space is [$0, 5]$ on both the $x$ axis and $y$ axis.

The set that satisfies the conditions overlaps with the sample space making that portion which overlaps the event space. I need to find the area of this event space. But, I don't know how I can do this. The event space is a triangle on the top right hand side of the square formed by the sample space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The triangle is a right triangle, so the problem reduces to finding the two short sides (why?). Since you know the coordinates of the point having a right angle, to get the length of the sides you need the coordinates of the two points where the boundary line intersects the two sides of the square.